# Ember js integrating with D3

Tags: d3.js, ember.js

I want to include a graphs which have 2-y axis with relevant 2 data sets in my ember project.

Since I am newbie to D3 js as well as ember js I do some googling and come up with npm packages for doing that like these `ember-d3`, `ember-charts`,  `ember-d3-helpers`. etc..

But all of them seems to me there is a bit of learning curve.
My questions are, from using those kind of packages can I integrate and draw my graphs?

Or else can I use directly D3 without any npm plunging?

Are there any suitable way to integrate D3 in ember project?

Answer (score 2):

The simplested solution I am currently using is to import your third part libraries using `ember-cli-build.js` (see code below)

```
/*jshint node:true*/
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
  });

  app.import('./bower_components/d3/d3.js');
  app.import('./bower_components/c3-0.4.11/c3.js');          
  app.import('./bower_components/c3-0.4.11/c3.css');

  return app.toTree();
};
```

The code above let you have global access to d3 and c3 (which means which lib can be direct accessed in your window object ).

C3 is a really simple and powerful reusable d3 chart library and I recommend to every new d3 users.

http://c3js.org/

After you have your libs ready, put your chart generate code inside the component's `didInsertElement` hook (below just a sample and you can make it better for sure)

```
didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    const chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            columns: []
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                categories: [

                ]
            }
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        },
        grid: {
            y: {show: true}
        }
    });

    this.set('globalChart.lineChart', chart);
},
```

You can read more about Ember dependencies management at,

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/